# Block network share access at client

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, smb

Is there a way to block another computer's network share on my computer? For example I want to block

> \\server\share

making it inaccessible from my local computer.

I may still need to access other shares on that server so I can't just add a host entry to map the server name to 127.0.0.1.

I do not have access to change the share or permissions on the server.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Do you not have control of *server*? Can you change the permissions on \\server\share to prevent users on your computer from accessing it?

Comment: Do you want to hide it or prevent someone from being able to access it?

Comment: I do not have access to the server. I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not work this way.  Permission/security to a share comes from the machine with the share, not the other way around.  Its up to the host computer to decide who has access to the share.

That does not mean it is not possible.  I can think of a workaround using a script.  If you have admin access to *your* machine, you can write a script that detects access to the share and terminates it.  Of course you could just terminate the script and gain access...